# When should atexit() be used?

Tags: libc, atexit

The GNU [page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Cleanups-on-Exit.html) says :

> Your program can arrange to run its own cleanup functions if normal termination happens. If you are writing a library for use in various application programs, then it is unreliable to insist that all applications call the library's cleanup functions explicitly before exiting. **It is much more robust to make the cleanup invisible to the application, by setting up a cleanup function in the library itself using atexit or on_exit**.

SDL in one of it's  [pages](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Quit)  says :

> You can use `SDL_Quit()` with `atexit()` to ensure that it is run when your application is shutdown, but it is not wise to do this from a library or other dynamically loaded code.

What I understood from the GNU page is that it encourages the usage of atexit() in programs.

Can someone elaborate on this, taken from the SDL page ? The meaning is not so obvious :

> *but it is not wise to do this from a library or other dynamically loaded code.*

What are the pitfalls that are to be avoided while using atexit() ?

Are the above two quotes contradicting each other ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, SDL is saying don't call `atexit(SDL_Quit)` from within a library. GNU advise you set up `atexit` within your library to avoid cleanup problems, SDL is saying don't call it from a different library - due to the manner in which dynamic code gets unloaded you can't be certain of ordering (especially in multithreaded apps).

Short version: call `atexit(SDL_Quit)` inside your program's main. If you are using or writing a wrapper library around SDL, *don't* call `atexit(SDL_Quit)` inside that library, instead call `atexit(YOURLIBRARY_Quit)` inside the main function (presuming that `YOURLIBRARY_Quit` will handle the call to `SDL_Quit`.

Comment: dynamic code is any code loaded at runtime, so linked libraries and anything you call using `dlopen`.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any more pitfalls that are to be avoided and taken care of ?

Answer (score 1):

atexit() is somehow like the dtor of c++ global/static object. One pitfall I have been seeing is, the atexit callbacks are called by exit() but the while the calling thread is running the callback other threads are also running so you need to make sure you don't have concurrency issue. Like in the dtor(of global/static obj), if you destroy something, other threads may still be using it so it might cause unexpected behavior.

But this is for Linux; not familiar with windows